# How to create a data frame from a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

So I managed to extract the data I needed from a CSV file and it looks like the table on the picture. Obviously the columns represent the years, and each row represents the month 1 = jan, 2 = february ...
How can I do to create a new data frame that has 120 rows: one for each month of the years 2004 to 2013; and two columns: one being the date and one being the value associated with the date (year and month)?

Thank you

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please don't post pictures of code and data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use melt to do something like this (it's called "going from wide to long format"). I simulated a data frame x that looks like your image:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- matrix(rexp(100, rate=.1), ncol=10) # simulate a 12 col x 10 row matrix
mos <- seq(1,12)
yrs <- seq(2004,2013)
colnames(x) <- yrs
x.df <- cbind(mos,x)
data_long <- melt(x.df, id.vars=c("mos"))
```